# C++ struct containing unsigned char and int bug

Tags: c++, struct, byte

Ok i have a struct in my C++ program that is like this:

```
struct thestruct
{
 unsigned char var1;
 unsigned char var2;
 unsigned char var3[2];
 unsigned char var4;
 unsigned char var5[8];
 int var6;
 unsigned char var7[4];
};
```

When i use this struct, 3 random bytes get added before the "var6", if i delete "var5" it's still before "var6" so i know it's always before the "var6".

But if i remove the "var6" then the 3 extra bytes are gone.

If i only use a struct with a int in it, there is no extra bytes.

So there seem to be a conflict between the unsigned char and the int, how can i fix that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler is probably using its default alignment option, where members of size *x* are aligned on a memory boundary evenly divisible by *x*.

Depending on your compiler, you can affect this behaviour using a [`#pragma` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1(v=VS.71).aspx), for example:

```
#pragma pack(1)
```

will turn off the default alignment in Visual C++:

> Specifies the value, in bytes, to be used for packing. The default value for *n* is 8. Valid values are 1, 2, 4, 8, and 16. The alignment of a member will be on a boundary that is either a multiple of *n* or a multiple of the size of the member, whichever is smaller.

Note that for low-level CPU performance reasons, it is usually best to try to align your data members so that they fall on an aligned boundary. Some CPU architectures *require* alignment, while others (such as Intel x86) tolerate misalignment with a decrease in performance (sometimes quite significantly).

Answer (score 5):

Your data structure being [aligned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) so that your int falls on word boundries, which for your target might be 32 or 64 bits.
You can reorganize your struct like so so that this won't happen:

```
struct thestruct
{
 int var6;
 unsigned char var1;
 unsigned char var2;
 unsigned char var3[2];
 unsigned char var4;
 unsigned char var5[8];
 unsigned char var7[4];
};
```

Comment: Good call on reorganizing the structure, much better than using compiler-dependent packing pragmas / attributes.

Comment: It is still implementation defined though.

Answer (score 4):

Are you talking about padding bytes?  That's not a bug.  As allowed by the C++ standard, the compiler is adding padding to keep the members [aligned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).  This is required for some architectures, and will greatly improve performance for others.

Answer (score 0):

You're having a byte alignment problem.  The compiler is adding padding to align the bytes. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) wikipedia article.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [data structure alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).  Essentially, depending on the compiler and compile options, you'll get alignment onto different powers-of-2.

To avoid it, move multi-byte items (**int** or pointers) before single-byte (signed or unsigned **char**) items -- although it might still be there *after* your last item.

Answer (score 0):

While rearranging the order you declare data members inside your `struct` is fine, it should be emphasized that overriding the default alignment by using `#pragma`s and such is a **bad idea** unless you know exactly what you're doing. Depending on your compiler and architecture, attempting to access unaligned data, particularly by storing the address in a pointer and later trying to dereference it, can easily give the dreaded Bus Error or other undefined behavior.